# Is there any method or way that I can get a value of an attribute of an object from a list of dynamics object's fields?

Tags: c#, linq, virtual, iqueryable, iqueryable.toarray

I need to get that single date which is underlined in red in the image, and store it into a variable, so I can create a conditional and use it as a param.

Through front end it comes dynamically thousands of fields and filters which this date is included, or it also can bring only the date. Therefore, DataFechamento will always come no matter how many filters are coming..

Any way, the thing is that for me to create the conditional that I need, only that date in DataFechamento matters. Therefore, I need to find out how I can pick that '31/08/2022' alone and store it inside a variable.

```
 public virtual IQueryable<Object> MontaQueryRecuperar(RecuperarIdDTO dto)
    {
        QueryParams queryParams = new QueryParams()
        {
            includes = dto.includes,
            limit = 1,
            page = 1,
            start = 0,
            fields = dto.fields,
            filter = "[{'property':'Id','operator':'equal','value':" + dto.Id + "}]"
        };
        var query = ExecutaConsulta(queryParams);

        IQueryable<object> queryFinal = query;

        var fields = queryParams.GetFields();

        if (fields != null && fields.Count > 0)
            queryFinal = (query.SelectDynamic<TEntidade>(fields) as IQueryable<object>);

        return queryFinal;
    }
```

[image]

just for analysis:
[image: just for analysis]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Images of text aren't searchable, or accessible, and it isn't easy for people trying to help you to copy the code and try running it. Please augment the images of code with the text they contain.

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.